# Is there any way of adding java swing actions to an array list?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to be able to undo and redo actions using an arraylist, by either jumping back or forward to actions in the arraylist. The program uses JButtons and a drop down menu that applies to changes.

Comment: Those sort of actions -- undo and redo -- you normally have to define and implement yourself.  I don't think Swing does that for you. (Edit: I blew all the dust off my Swing Hacks book, let's see if there's anything in here.)

Comment: [`UndoManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html)? So far, you have a wish list. You know you want to use an `ArrayList`, you know you want to use it as a FILO queue, it sounds like you know what you want to add to it. So I don't know what's stopping you or what your question actually is

Comment: A stack sounds more promising for your use case

Answer (score 0):

A quick work-around to that is using a Stack.

Everytime before performing a modification to your ArrayList, you could push a copy of the ArrayList into the stack, then modify the current ArrayList.

That way, you could use a simple JButton in order to "undo" and pop the previous state of the ArrayList.

Some pseudocode could be:

```
// prior to modify the ArrayList
myStack.push(copyof(this.ArrayList));
// Modify the ArrayList...
```

And:

```
// Oops, user got in trouble. better restore last previous "ok" state.
this.ArrayList = myStack.pop();
```